# Advantage of RxJava2 over AsyncTask

Tags: android, rx-java2

Hi I am reading about `rxjava2` which is basically for async operations. I found it has an operator concept which `AsyncTask` in android does not.

How else is `rxjava2` different than `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @VygintasB I'm pretty sure that If you don't handle subscriptions appropriately it can, and will, give memory leaks so its a bit misleading to say it doesn't, and an incorrect comparison.

Comment: I don't see a point in downvoting OP's answer. @BobDalgeish's answer should be upvoted to alleviate uninitiated confusion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RxJava is not "basically for async operation". That is only one aspect of it.

1. RxJava allows you to compose operations on data, such that the output of one operation can be used as the input to the next. This operates similarly to streams implementations.
2. RxJava uses this composability to allow some operations to occur in a multi-threaded environment. It does this by providing well-defined semantics for the operators when working with multiple schedulers. RxJava can use `asyncTask` to perform some operations.
3. RxJava manages back pressure requirements for some applications by using `Flowable` chains, while `Observable` chains have no back pressure requirements. The former is appropriate where buffering is required or explicit acknowledgment of dropped information needs to be made.
4. RxJava has clear error and error handling semantics.

`asyncTask` just handles asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `AsyncTask` is an Android construct, where RxJava is pure Java, not that it makes the quality of the OP's original better though!

Answer (score 3):

`AsyncTask` is Android’s default tool for developers needing to do some simple long-ish running work in the context of a UI screen without blocking the UI.

The main problem with AsyncTask is:

- **MULTIPLE WEB SERVICE CALLS**:

  To solve this in `AsyncTask` create an inner AsyncTask subclass in our Activity/Fragment, perform the network operation in the background, and take the result of that operation and update the UI in the main thread.

  this approach has some issues and limitations:

  **Memory/context leaks** are easily created is an inner class and thus holds an implicit reference to the outer class Also, what if we want to chain another long operation after the network call? We’d have to nest two AsyncTasks which can significantly reduce readability.
- **ERROR HANDLING**

  What happens if something goes wrong? Unfortunately, there’s no out-of-the-box solution for this.
  And other problem like device rotation, back press handle etc.

To solved this all problem look at **RxJava**

Handle Error using RxJava is like this:

```
webService.doSomething(someData)
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(
              result -> resultText.setText("It worked!"),
              e -> handleError(e));
```

Second, In multiple web services call.

```
public Observable<List<Weather>> getWeatherForLargeUsCapitals() {
  return cityDirectory.getUsCapitals()
                      .flatMap(cityList -> Observable.from(cityList))
                      .filter(city -> city.getPopulation() > 500,000)
                      .flatMap(city -> weatherService.getCurrentWeather(city)) //each runs in parallel
                      .toSortedList((cw1,cw2) -> cw1.getCityName().compare(cw2.getCityName()));
}
```

Hope this may help you!!

Comment: What do you mean by "device rotation, back press handle etc." - Asyntask keep running what about rxjava ?

Comment: If you use RxLifecycle library then .compose(bindToLifecycle()) handle lifecycle callback.

Comment: What it does ` .compose(bindToLifecycle()) ` ? does it cancel on rotation and back press ?

Comment: bindToLifecycle() will hook your Observable chain into the Fragment lifecycle callback events and auto-unsubscribe causing execution to stop so that there’s no risk of running your Fragment subscription code in an invalid state.

Comment: RxLifecycle has been deprecated by its author. Read more here: http://blog.danlew.net/2017/08/02/why-not-rxlifecycle/